# Mesibo - How to change toolbar color in Android

Tags: android, colors, mesibo

I am working with Mesibo SDK for android and I am trying to change the toolbar color without results.

I would to like to change both colors:
https://ibb.co/LrXf4d8

I tried to edit colors.xml and styles.xml but nothing is changing.

Someone has the solution?

I paste part of code.

activity_settings.xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the colors.xml file I changed colorPrimary but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

to change the status bar (the notification bar):

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

to change the title bar:

[image]

change the value of "colorPrimary"

Comment: yes, I tried to change value on colorPrimary in colors.xml file but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getConfig()` to get the configuration instance and then use `Config.mToolbarColor` to set the color. You need to use ARGB color.

You can refer to the source code is here for other configurable properties

https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MesiboUI.java

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am working on android source code, is not possible to change it only editing colors.xml file?

Because, on your documents there are not informations to use getConfig() and Config.mToolbarColor

Comment: If you want it in a particular way, you can download the source code, modify and compile it yourself. It is open-source.

Comment: Hi friend, thank you for your message. I downloaded the code from github. I started the code via android studio and I opened the colors.xml file. In this file I changed <color name="colorPrimary">#fff222</color> and <color name="myPrimaryColor">#ff00868b</color>. I have installed the app on my phone but nothing has been changed. No way to change the colors editing the colors.xml file

Comment: please check this image: https://ibb.co/RHG78fG . As you can see the button and others color has been changed. But the toolbar, blue and green colors, does not change colors..